# Sorting table in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I wan to sort a table columns which have following html:

```
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="orderByField='taskName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Task</th>
        <th data-ng-repeat="day in days"><span>Day:</span> {{day.toDate() | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="(key,t) in jobs | filter: searchKeyword | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
        <td>{{t.taskName}}</td>
        <td data-ng-repeat="day in days">
            <div data-ng-repeat="c in t[day.format('YYYYMMDD')]">
                <span>{{c.completeDate | date:'H:mm'}}</span> {{c.nurseName}}

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

result view is

[image]

I want to make sorting on a time like if i click on the header of any particular day then it will sort out all the task of the given day by showing time. 
I have implement a function in my controller for srting:

```
$scope.sort = {
    column: '',
    descending: false
};
$scope.changeSorting = function(column) {
    $log.info(column);

    var sort = $scope.sort;

    if (sort.column == column) {
        sort.descending = !sort.descending;
    } else {
        sort.column = column;
        sort.descending = false;
    }
};
```

but unable to find a clue how i can apply in this situation where i need to apply sorting on a time within a date. Can someone give me hint.

Comment: You can use the orderBy filder: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy - use a scope variable for the sort by value, and assign a new value when headers are clicked.

Comment: you mean i need to apply sorting on date ? i need to sort on a time of a day when click on particular header day

Answer (score 0):

```
<th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'date'; reverse = !reverse">Date</a></th>
                                    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'name'; reverse = !reverse">Name</a></th>
                                    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'detail'; reverse = !reverse">detail</a></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it fir by default to first column name

```
$scope.sort = {
    column: 'Task',
    descending: false
};

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="sort.column='Task'; sort.descending= !sort.descending">Task</th>
        <th data-ng-repeat="day in days"><span>Day:</span> {{day.toDate() | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
        </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
```

Change the ng-repeat to:

```
ng-repeat="(key,t) in (jobs | filter: searchKeyword | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending)"
```

You don't need any extra code in controller to sort, like your method changesort etc. just remove that.